# Is there a different uploader for the Channel Form that can upload images instantly?

Tags: file-uploads, channel-form

I am building a channel form for creating entries outside the control panel and I am having a small problem with uploads.

The form allows the user to upload 6 image files and the way I do it is by having 6 separate file upload fields. If try to create an entry from the control panel, I can upload each file separately. So when I am done completing the form and hit submit everything is posted almost instantly. On the channel form though the problem is that the user selects the files to upload for each one of the 6 file upload fields, but ALL the files are uploaded only once the user hits the submit button. Now imagine having 6 separate 1MB files… it could take ages for the upload to complete.

A potential solution could be to disable the submit button once the user presses it and maybe show a message informing them that this might take a while based on the file sizes. But I believe that it would be better to have a different uploader. Something that would upload the files instantly and let the user move one with the rest of the form. A preview of the uploaded image would be nice too. :-)

Does anyone know something like this for ExpressionEngine? Is there an uploader plugin that can do what I want or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Mega Upload (http://www.devdemon.com/mega_upload) would be a good add-on to look into for this. I use it for my channel forms.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Photo Frame. It does exactly what you want.

Docs
https://objectivehtml.com/photo-frame

Devot:ee
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/photo-frame